# trying to code a script to move to the endgame screen on contact with a sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when the player touches the portal a script on the portal (below) should make it so the scene index goes up by 1 changing scene but this now happens whenever the player makes contact with anything? help?

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        Debug.Log("End");

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the code to increment your scene index is outside of the scope of the if statement. You need to use brackets so that it will include that function.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("End");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Also, for 'OnTriggerEnter2D', you can just use `other.CompareTag` instead of `other.gameObject.CompareTag`

Comment: thank you, didn't realise I just forget brackets aha. that's embarrassing.